# Pacemaker - Logging the result of a ping check?

Tags: networking, pacemaker, corosync

I read this page and the next: https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/deprecated/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Pacemaker_Explained/_moving_resources_due_to_connectivity_changes.html

And it explains how to set up a ping that you can link to the allocation of a resource.

While this works, if I have more than 1 URL or more than 1 ping check, how can I know which one is failing?

It seems this isn't logged anywhere if it occurs. It just occurs and pacemaker makes a decision...

Reading this source code: https://github.com/ClusterLabs/pacemaker/blob/master/extra/resources/ping

It seems a debug environment variable needs to be enabled. I'd rather not do this, assuming I have to restart pacemaker for it and thus messing up allocations, plus whatever amount of extra logs will now be taking up disk space.

Is there a way to just only log a single line if a ping failed, saying only that, and affecting nothing else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the debug option isn't just an environment variable, it can be set on the ping resource itself, like this:

```
pcs resource update ping debug=1
```

The only downside is: the log doesn't appear in `/var/log/pacemaker.log` as expected but in `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the resource agent's (RA) source, it looks like enabling the debug option by setting it to `warn` is what you'd want to do.

If for some reason that behavior isn't what you want, changing the `1)` case statement in the `ping_check()` function as shown below (line 305 in the ping RA) might be what you're looking for:

```
ping_check() {
    active=0
    for host in $OCF_RESKEY_host_list; do
        p_exe=ping

        case $(uname) in
            Linux) p_args="-n -q -W $OCF_RESKEY_timeout -c $OCF_RESKEY_attempts";;
            Darwin) p_args="-n -q -t $OCF_RESKEY_timeout -c $OCF_RESKEY_attempts -o";;
            FreeBSD) p_args="-n -q -t $OCF_RESKEY_timeout -c $OCF_RESKEY_attempts -o";;
            *) ocf_log err "Unknown host type: $(uname)"; exit $OCF_ERR_INSTALLED;;
        esac

        case "$host" in
            *:*) p_exe=ping6
        esac

        ping_output=$($p_exe $p_args $OCF_RESKEY_options $host 2>&1); rc=$?

        case $rc in
            0)
                active=$(expr $active + 1)
                if [ $OCF_RESKEY_debug -gt 1 ]; then
                    ping_conditional_log info "$ping_output"
                fi
                ;;
            1) ocf_log warn "$host is inactive: $ping_output";;
            *) ocf_log err "Unexpected result for '$p_exe $p_args $OCF_RESKEY_options $host' $rc: $ping_output";;
        esac
```

But that change looks like it will follow the same logic as setting the param `debug=warn`. I haven't tested this, just following the logic in the RA.

Also, if you do need to restart Pacemaker for some reason you can always put the cluster into `maintenance-mode=true` before doing so. If `maintenance-mode=true` is set Pacemaker will not start/stop/monitor services even while restarting. Just remember to set `maintenance-mode=false` when you're done.

Comment: Both these options seem like they will generate a lot more logs, and also restarting pacemaker is not an option for me. Thanks for your thorough look at it.